# How to launch two threads and wait for them

Tags: clojure

I can launch two threads and they work, but synchronously. What am I missing to get these threads independently launched?

### main, thread, and output

```
(defn -main 
    [& args]
    (do
        (let [grid-dim-in [0 5]
              mr1-pos     [\N 2 4]
              mr2-pos     [\N 1 5]
              mr1-movs    "LMLMMRMM"
              mr2-movs    "RMRMMMLM"]

            (reset! grid-dim grid-dim-in)
            (reset! mr1-id {:mr1 mr1-pos})
            (reset! mr2-id {:mr2 mr2-pos})

            (.start (Thread. (rover-thread mr1-id mr1-movs update-work-block)))
            (.start (Thread. (rover-thread mr2-id mr2-movs update-work-block))))))

(defn rover-thread [id movs update-ref]
    (let [id-key (keys @id)
          id-vals (vals @id)]
        (doseq [mov movs]
           (println "Rover " id-key " is moving ")
           (let [new-mov (determine-rover-move (first id-vals) mov)]
               (move-rover id new-mov update-ref)
               (print "Rover ")
               (print (first id-key))
               (print " is at ")
               (println new-mov)
               (Thread/sleep (rand 1000)))))

Rover :mr1 is at [E 2 4]
Rover  (:mr1)  is moving 
Rover :mr1 is at [N 2 5]
Rover  (:mr1)  is moving 
Rover :mr1 is at [N 2 5]
Finished on Thread[main,5,main]
Rover  (:mr2)  is moving 
Rover :mr2 is at [E 1 5]
Rover  (:mr2)  is moving 
Rover :mr2 is at [N 1 6]
```

Comment: generally, to solve problems like these, it can help to try and narrow down what your problem is by creating a test program that is as small as possible and still shows the behaviour you're trying to understand. Another benefit of this would be that such a test program is small and self-contained, so if you'd paste it here the community would be able to run the code themselves.

Your code contains references to functions not defined here, and several bits of code that are probably not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a close look at these two lines:

```
(.start (Thread. (rover-thread mr1-id mr1-movs update-work-block)))
(.start (Thread. (rover-thread mr2-id mr2-movs update-work-block))))))
```

This code evaluates the `(rover-thread mr1-id mr1-movs update-work-block)` first, and passes the result of that to the constructor of `Thread`, which is not what you want.

Here's a simple function to illustrate the principle. This doesn't work, because the `(f ...)` is evaluated before its result it passed to the `Thread` constructor:

```
(defn run-thread-thing-wrong []
  (let [f (fn [n s]
            (doseq [i (range n)]
              (prn s i)
              (Thread/sleep (rand 1000))))]
    (.start (Thread. (f 10 "A")))
    (.start (Thread. (f 10 "B"))))
  nil)
```

Here's a version that does work. A *function* is passed to the `Thread` constructor instead:

```
(defn run-thread-thing []
  (let [f (fn [n s]
            (doseq [i (range n)]
              (prn s i)
              (Thread/sleep (rand 1000))))]
    (.start (Thread. (fn [] (f 10 "A"))))
    (.start (Thread. (fn [] (f 10 "B")))))
  nil)
```

Note: instead of `(fn [] ....)` you can use the short form `#(....)` for anonymous functions.

Here's another version that does the same, but with a `future` instead of manually creating threads:

```
(defn run-thread-thing []
  (let [f (fn [n s]
            (doseq [i (range n)]
              (prn s i)
              (Thread/sleep (rand 1000))))]
    (future (f 10 "A"))
    (future (f 10 "B")))
  nil)
```

Note that in this case, you pass a form to `future` instead of a function.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a really good place to use Clojure's [agent feature](http://clojure.org/agents).  I am not qualified to fully explain how to use them, but a really good example of their usage can be found [here](https://github.com/krukow/ants-demo).  Starting threads using agents is dead-easy, and I think it is more idiomatic.

The code would look something like,

```
(def rover1 (agent [mr1-posn mr1-movs mr1-id])) 
(def rover2 (agent [mr2-posn mr2-movs mr2-id])) 
(defn rover-behave [[posn movs id]]
  (send-off *agent* #'rover-behave)
  (. Thread (sleep 1000))
  (let [new-mov (determine-rover-move posn movs id)
        new-posn (posn-after-move posn new-mov)]
    ;return value updates state of agent
    [new-posn movs id]
  )
)
(send-off rover1 rover-behave)
(send-off rover2 rover-behave)
```